# Film - a book is the villain's weak spot

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember when I was a kid ('90) my older siblings and cousins were watching a movie and I saw some parts of it. I wonder what the movie is called.
It was some kind of horror. There were a group of people and these people were running from a man (like in no other horror movie ;)), but what was significant in this movie was that there was a magic book. It seemed like the bad guy was vulnerable only by that magic book and when these people were stabbed the book, the man was bled and his blood was black.

Is there any movie like this or was it just my imagination?

Comment: I doubt it but is sort of similar to Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets with [Tom Riddle's diary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hkrGES1mcU).

Comment: Can you remember anything else though? At the moment your details are quite vague so it might be hard to pin down the story.

Comment: Action was in present times (then so about '80 - '90), bad gay was probably tall blond male. I remember some cars... and I guess that's it.

Comment: @Rumid: Try going to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and reading through the questions to see if it prompts any memories.

Comment: Long shot: Warlock.

Comment: Hmmm this might be it. I will watch trailer, some fragments to be sure. I saw some images and there was some man  and black blood. I've watched only some parts and as I remember the villain was rather less talkative, more mysterious. In warlock he plays main part. I might be wrong, it was long ago. I will check it

Comment: Can you remember any more details about e.g. the appearance of the book, what they stabbed it with, whether that came out of a hat, etc?

Comment: @WillCrawford - Great - saying "came out of a hat" made me remember [Lidsville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidsville). A complete non-sequitur (to almost *any* discussion). Thanks a heap, dude.

Comment: Was it as much like *Pinky and Perky, Live Action Role Play Edition* as it sounds?